# Why "_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_" occurs in Jupyter?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, janusgraph, gremlinpython

I was trying to reach the janusgraph deployed inside the GKE cluster, using the below code.

```
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal

g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('gs://private_network:8182/janusgraph','g'))
count = g.V().has('name','hercules').valueMap()
print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

when using Python you need to end the call with a "terminal" step. These steps include `next`, `toList` and `iterate`.

In this case as you are returning a single result (a `valueMap`) using `next` is sufficient.

Side note - the example code is a little confusing as the code is not returning a "count". Anyway, please try:

```py
count = g.V().has('name','hercules').valueMap().next()
```